# Tips on designing a Windows Phone Game that can be Ported to iOS/Monotouch

Tags: .net, ios, windows-phone-7, xamarin.ios

So i was thinking about giving windows phone game development a go. This is my first game and i want to make sure i design it in a way that can easily be ported to monotouch. does anyone know of any tips or resources that would be useful to know before designing it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Watch what API [MonoGame](http://monogame.codeplex.com/) supports and try to stay as close as possible to it. It should make porting your game much easier to MonoTouch (and a lot of other platforms as well).